# When Using Firefox, Zoom Launches Invalid Meeting ID

Tags: firefox, tabs, startup, browser-history, zoom-sdk

The title pretty much describes it. At seemingly random times while I am browsing in Firefox my Zoom desktop application will start and show the message

> **Invalid meeting ID**
>
> Please check and try again.

Simultaneously, a new tab will automatically open to my organization's authentication web page. Something seems to be trying to start a non-existent Zoom meeting, but I have no idea what or why. I am not signed into Zoom, Zoom was not running in the background, I have the setting "Start Zoom when I start Windows" unchecked, and I have no scheduled upcoming meetings at the moment.

I have googled every combination of terms I can think of, but the only potentially relevant item I found was a question from 2017 on Mozilla's support site:

> **JimWilliams**
>
> 11/28/17, 6:15 AM
>
> [**Every time I open Firefox it opens a nonexistent Zoom Meeting where it tells me the host has not joined the meeting -- takes too much time. Help!**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1191216)
>
> There is no reason I can find that a Zoom Meeting window opens every time I open Firefox -- I even signed up for Zoom so I could make sure it didn't show I had any meetings scheduled recurring or otherwise.  But having done that and rebooted -- a Zoom Meeting window opens asking me to join a nonexistent recurring meeting where it indicates it is waiting for the host to initiate the meeting.  Takes forever (it seems).  How can I end this problem?
>
> > [...several unhelpful replies hidden...]
>
> > **jscher2000 - Support Volunteer | Top 10 Contributor**
> >
> > 11/30/17, 9:23 PM
> >
> > In Firefox 56 and earlier, with the old "new tab page," sometimes a tile from history would trigger an odd behavior such a message that Firefox wanted to launch a different application. The approach to that was to remove any tiles that might trigger the unwanted behavior. I don't know if that is an issue with the new "Activity Stream" page, or whether you have that page as your home page.
> >
> > Example old thread: [Why does another application launch when I open a new tab? Plug-in is in Firefox and I can't get ride of it.](https://support.mozilla.org/questions/1128512)

This question seems to match my own, but the reply blames an old version of Firefox (I am using Firefox 102.0.1) and the new-tab page (which I don't think I had open when this problem occurred). However, based on the thread's suggestion, I deleted every page from my browser history containing the term "zoom" and I'll wait to see if doing so resolved the bug.

(P.S. I apologize to the mods for the zoom-sdk tag. I can't find an existing tag relating to general Zoom questions. Please feel free to edit if you have better tag ideas.)

Comment: Could you explain the -1 please?

Comment: Your question is off topic on Stack Overflow, delete it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So far, removing any Zoom-related tiles on the new tab page and deleting any page from browser history mentioning "zoom" seems to have worked. The only question that remains is why this is still a bug in Firefox after so many updates.